# jetty with log4j configuration

Tags: java, log4j, jetty, slf4j

I was able to set up log4j for my web application fine, but am having a difficult time configuring jetty log messages to use log4j. I keep getting this

```
Establishing start.log on Thu Jul 05 16:44:54 PDT 2012
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.eclipse.jetty.util.log).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

I practically copied and pasted my log4j.properties file in every single directories in my jetty home (lib, etc, contexts, resources, webapps). I currently have log4j-1.2.17.jar, slf4j-api-1.6.5.jar, and slf4j-log4j12-1.6.5.jar in lib/ext which jetty seems to detect fine.

Any ideas? Thanks